# Is "Hello everyone!" a complete sentence?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-meaning, idiomatic-language

1. Is "Hello everyone!" a complete sentence?

We have this thing of greeting people when we start working in a Slack channel. People use different greetings, say "good morning" or simply "Hi all!", I understand that all these are informal but with regards to  "Hello everyone!", is it a complete sentence?

I mean, does it sound like the person is going to say something more (similar to interjections)?

Is it okay to use it when I just want to greet people and say nothing more?

2. Also, is it common to use "Good afternoon!" as a greeting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a complete utterance. It doesn't require anything else and listeners would not require you to say anything more.

Whether it is a sentence or not is more doubtful. It doesn't have a main finite clause.  Most greetings are complete interjections like this. Just because something is an interjection doesn't make it a fragment. "Good afternoon!" is another common greeting.  (Surely most of these greetings are taught very early in a language course)

Answer (score 1):

*Hello, everyone!*, a greeting addressed to all those present or listening, is a valid sentence.

*Good morning/afternoon/evening* are all common greetings, a little more formal than *hello* or *hi. Good night* is usually reserved for parting.